# Maximizing node weight sum while traversing a weighted edges

Tags: algorithm, optimization, graph

I have a graph

- With a start node 'S'.
- It is such that there is only one path to every node in the graph starting from 'S'
- Each node has a weight
- Each edge is weighed and it is the cost of moving between the nodes it connects. And also this cost is one time i.e. once we move say from 'S' to 'N1', there is no cost involved for future movements between 'S' and 'N1'

The problem is - Given a number B , start travel from 'S' such that the sum of the weight of the nodes visited is maximized and and cost encountered is less than or equal to B.

Sorry , I have no rights to post images here.So here is an external link to it:

http://postimg.org/image/4fpf0xtkp/

For eg in the above graph I can traverse as below:

S->N1->N2->N1->N3->N4 with node weight = N1+N2+N3+N4 (which is maximized) 
and total cost L1+L2+L3+L4 (which is within B)

Help is appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is NP-hard. To see this, assume that you have your node S and every other node is connected to S by an edge, and there are no other edges. Further assume that the weight of each node is equal to the cost of its edge. Then, for a given target maximum cost B, if you could solve your problem then you could solve the subset sum problem (given B, determine if there is a subset of costs that adds up to exactly B). Thus, your problem is NP-hard and there is probably no fast algorithm to solve it. Brute force methods are straightforward and might end up being the best way to go.